# Is there any way out for faster filling of NULL Values in big dataframe in python. as fillna is causing memory error out for me

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

Is there any way out for faster filling of NULL Values in big dataframe in python. as fillna is causing memory error out for me.

Error

```
  File "C:\Users\<>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py", line 729, in astype_nansafe
    return arr.astype(dtype, copy=True)

MemoryError
```

Comment: Could you please share some details about the dataframe at hand and about your code?

Comment: @Roy2012 : Dataframe contains of 500 columns and about to 13000 rows with approx to 60 columns having complete NULL values to it.So when I am using str_cols =  new.columns[new.dtypes==object]
new[str_cols] = new[str_cols].fillna('.')
new.fillna('NA',inplace=True)

Comment: But this is taking too long to process and is causing memory out.

Comment: One thing you should probably do is run this line as in place: new[str_cols] = new[str_cols].fillna('.')

Comment: @Roy2012 there is no change in it.Could you let me know what to change.@cs95

Comment: Do you know where do you run out of memory? When you fillna for the object columns, or on the next line?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217551/discussion-between-manisha-and-roy2012).